# Angular router does not navigate to set url but to empty url path

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am currently developing an angular app using its router functionality. All routes seem to have been working well until I found out that after a successful login, the url path I've set it to, which is '/admin' will not be followed and the router instead defaults to a '/'. This is the code:

```
//login.component.ts
if (this.authService.getUserRole() == 'user' || 'agent') {
window.location.assign('/')
} else if (this.authService.getUserRole() == 'admin') {
window.location.assign('/admin')
}



//app.routing.ts
import {AdminComponent} from './admin-master/admin/admin.component;
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component;

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {permission:{only: ['admin']}}}
]
```

**EDIT: (added auth.guard.ts)**

```
//auth.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

      const permission = next.data["permission"];

      if(this.authService.isLoggedIn() &&
      permission.only.includes(this.authService.getUserRole())) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/logout');
      }
    
  }
  
}
```

**The Problem:**

1. Although a successful login has been done, the router will redirect a user to a blank url instead of the set URL I have provided specifically in the `login.component.ts` folder.
2. Because it will redirect to an empty URL, elements from the `home.component.html` will also display within my admin dashboard which I don't want to happen.

In conclusion, how do I route the following functions correctly? Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you see in your browser console (<kbd>F12</kbd>)

Comment: @Pieterjan This is what immediately shows in my Router event: Navigation Start:`NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')`

Comment: What your `AuthGuard` looks like ? 
Also your routing looks a little strange to me, you're not using the angular build in routing functionality (https://angular.io/guide/router) 
Instead of `window.location.assign('/admin')` you should use 
`this.router.navigate(['admin'], { relativeTo: this.route });`

Comment: I'll edit my post to add the AuthGuard! Also, the reason I used `window.location.assign` is to trick the browser into thinking that I've already redirected to the route. This is due to some of my functionalities only loading if I refresh the application.

Comment: @Pieterjan any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your code on github.com? Just create a repo, `git clone [url]`, paste your files inside the folder, `git add .`, `git commit`, `git push`, and share the url to your repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `app.routing.ts` file, I've observed that from the code below, removing `{useHash: true}` would result in a correct URL redirect. This is due to the fact that adding `{useHash: true}` adds an extra `/#` to my url resulting in defaulting to a blank URL because it does not match any routes.

`export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true, enableTracing: true });`

I've modified it instead to:

`export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);`

NOTE: I've also removed `enableTracing: true` just to clean up my console results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Router` instead of `window.location.assign` to navigate into different URL's

Example:

```
import { Router} from '@angular/router';

/* Login Component */

constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

navigate() {
    if (this.authService.getUserRole() == 'user' || 'agent') {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
    } else if (this.authService.getUserRole() == 'admin') {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin')
    }
}
```

check the doc [https://angular.io/api/router/Router](https://angular.io/api/router)

Comment: I've tried this before, but it still does not navigate to my desired route although the login has been successful. The reason why I used window.location.assign is to trick the browser to and to load the new components that I navigated to.

Comment: This is the code you should be able to use. I'm very much under the impression that the URL you want to navigate to does not exist. Normally you would get an error in the browser console with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Replace window.location.assign('/admin')

with

```
this.router.navigate([‘../admin’], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

router : Router
route : ActivatedRoute

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: can you provide how you added the router to the constructor? Can't seem to replicate your solution.

Comment: Inject Router just like u do activatedRoute

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are navigating to the admin page ?
Your code looks wrong I think.

```
if (this.authService.getUserRole() == 'user' || 'agent') {
    window.location.assign('/')
} else if (this.authService.getUserRole() == 'admin') {
    window.location.assign('/admin')
}
```

it should be like below otherwise the first one is always true because of `|| 'agent'`

```
const role = this.authService.getUserRole();
if (role  === 'user' || role === 'agent') {
    window.location.assign('/')
} else if (role  === 'admin') {
    window.location.assign('/admin')
}
```

also I prefer `===` for value and type checking.

Comment: thank you for pointing out one of my mistakes. `|| role === 'agent'` should've been the right code. Nevertheless, I have found the answer to my problem. I'll post an answer soon!